# Using WebServiceHost in desktop apps

Tags: c#, webservicehost

I'm hosting a service using WebServiceHost in my desktop application and not closing this service if the process is terminated. I checked the port I used after the process terminates and it was closed, and I was able to reuse the same port properly.

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405496(v=vs.110).aspx) thread, the close only switch the state for the WebServiceHost object.

I found no threads warns not to use close. Does the desktop application disposes the object properly when done? Or it is required to close the service as the app terminates.

```
WebServiceHost WCFService = new WebServiceHost(wcs, httpBaseAddress);
WCFService.Open();
WCFService.Close(); // Is this line of code required when using WebServiceHost
```